# Slice syntax for python 2.7, reverse a part of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How do I use the slice syntax of python to get a list from `0` to `i` in reversed order?

For example, if the list is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `i == 2`, the result should be `[3 ,2 ,1]`.

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 is the first character instead of the second because it takes effect after the reversal (you take steps backwards)

```
>>> [1,2,3,4][2::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```